# python: invoking socket.recvfrom() twice

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am writing two python scripts to communicate over UDP using python *sockets*. Here's the related part of code

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.setblocking(True) #I want it to be blocking
#(...)
(msg, addr) = sock.recvfrom(4)
#(...)
(msg2, addr2) = sock.recvfrom(2)
```

I want the receiving to be blocking and I don't know the size of the whole message before I read the first 4-byte part. The above code becomes blocked on the  `sock.recvrfom(2)` part, whereas modified, with one `sock.recvfrom` instead of two works alright:

```
(msg, addr) = sock.recvfrom(6) #works ok, but isn't enough for my needs
```

Any idea how I can conveniently read the incoming data in two parts or why the code doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`socket.recvfrom(size)` will (for UDP sockets) read one packet, up to `size` bytes. The excess data is *discarded*. If you want to receive the whole packet, you have to pass a larger bufsize, then process the packet in bits (instead of trying to receive it in bits.)

If you want a more convenient, less fickle interface to network I/O, consider [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com).

Answer (score 2):

Read from UDP socket dequeues *the whole datagram*.

Answer (score 1):

UDP is a message-based protocol.  `recvfrom` will read the entire message that was originally sent, but if the buffer isn't big enough, it will throw an exception:

> socket.error: [Errno 10040] A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself

So I am not sure why you would hang on the 2nd `recvfrom` if a 6-byte message was originally sent.  You should throw an exception on the first `recvfrom`.  Perhaps post an actual working, minimal example of the client and the server program.